# Power shell code to remove special characters in the column headers(.csv file)

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0

I'm trying to loop through 40 CSV files in a path and remove any characters that are not numeric,alphabets and space values only in the headers.

Below is my code i tried working on, This is working for headers in the files but also its replacing all the data in the file and i can see only headers without special characters in it, i'm just a beginner in power shell, not sure how to proceed further any help is much appreciated.

```
$path = "C:\AllFiles\"

Get-ChildItem -path $path -Filter *.csv | 

Foreach-Object {

$content = Get-Content $_.FullName

$content[0] = $content[0] -replace '[^0-9a-zA-Z, ]'|Set-Content $_.FullName

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the trick and should be the fastest method:

```
$path = 'C:\AllFiles\'

$collection = Get-ChildItem -path $path -Filter *.csv' 

foreach( $file in $collection ) {

    $content = [System.IO.File]::ReadAllLines( $file.FullName )

    $content[0] = $content[0] -replace '[^0-9a-zA-Z, ]'

    [System.IO.File]::WriteAllLines( $file.FullName, $content ) | Out-Null 
}
```

Comment: Thank you, this worked without altering the file structure :)

Comment: Hi... I was trying to remove the trailing spaces in the column values and added the below code   "$content[0] = $content[0] -replace '[^0-9a-zA-Z, ]'.TrimEnd()" to do the trick... but doesn't seem to be removing it... Would you be able to guide me on this one.. thanks

Comment: Just enter a new line: $content[0] = ($content[0]).Trim()

Answer (score 2):

The -replace operator requires two values, the first value is what you are looking for, and the second value is what to replace the first value with.

EXAMPLE: 
`"John Jones" -replace "Jones","Smith"`

This will replace "Jones" with the text "Smith" creating a new string "John Smith"

In your example, instead of creating a regex of what you want to keep, create a regex of what you want to replace.

EXAMPLE:

```
$path = "C:\AllFiles\"

Get-ChildItem -path $path -Filter *.csv | 
Foreach-Object {

$content = Get-Content -Path $path

$content[0] = $content[0] -replace '[regex for special chars]',""

Set-Content $path -value $content -force
}
```

This will replace the whole string, with a string where you've replaced the regex values with ""

Comment: Hello, thanks for your response ! I already have the code "replace '[^0-9a-zA-Z, ]'" that would replace any characters that are in this regex and it is working... my only concern is that "set-content" overwrites all the data in the file also correcting the headers

Answer (score 1):

Pretty close, try it like this instead:

```
$path = "C:\temp"
Get-ChildItem -path $path -Filter *.csv | 
    Foreach-Object {
    $content = Get-Content $_
    $content[0] = $content[0] -replace '[^a-zA-Z0-9, ]',''
    $content | Out-File $_
}
```

This will only clear special characters on the first line but leaves the rest of the file untouched.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
dir "C:\AllFiles" -Filter *.csv | % {
  (Get-Content $_.FullName)[0] -replace '[\W]', '' | Set-Content $_.FullName -Force
}
```